# C++ is not Giving Expected output

Tags: c++

I'm Student of I.T In our Text Book there are so many programs of Simple inheritance but those are very long practicals so its very Difficult to understand and very difficult to remember so I tried to make a small simple inheritance program in C++ but The program is not giving the expected output.

I've Used C++ for windows 7

Here is the code :

```
#include"iostream.h" 
#include"conio.h"

class A
{
public:
int a,b;

void setData(int i,int j)
{
   a=i;
   b=j;

}

};
class B: public A
{
   public:
   int compare()
   {
  return(a>b?a:b);
   }

};


void main()
{
A a;
B b;
//int c;
clrscr();

a.setData(25,9);


cout<<"answer: "<<b.compare();

getch();

}
```

Output is like this

```
answer : 1213
```

So plz help me N tell me Why the Output is like this !!!! 
I just want to learn

Comment: Why did you tag this in 5 languages?

Comment: Get basic idea about class, object... etc. first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `setData` on object of class `A` , but calling `compare` on object of class `B`. Use `b` in both case.

```
int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  //int c;
  clrscr();

  b.setData(25,9);


  cout<<"answer: "<<b.compare();

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

also change signature of `main` method.

Comment: I'm Sorry What did u say I didn't get you O.o 
Can you Please Explain !!! In detail!!

Comment: There is no more detail. You are using two different object in two method calls. Use the object of `B` type. I showed you the code.

Comment: Hey It Works (y) Thnq Sir

Answer (score 0):

`a` and  `b` are different objects, the variables `a,b` store at memory space of each object. You initialised members of `a`  and tried to compare with object `b`

`So plz help me N tell me Why the Output is like this?`

whatever you get as answer is some junk value.